# Two UITableViewCells in my XIB for iPad/iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xib

I am trying to use two differently formatted UITableViewCells depending on if it's an iPad or iPhone. Both the cells show the same information, but the iPad cell has half the height and double the width. So the information is shown on one line vs two lines.

In my `cellforRowatIndexPath`,

I am putting the code:

```
HistoryCell *cell;
if (self.isiPad) {
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"historyiPadCellType" forIndexPath:indexPath];

}
else{
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"historyCellType" forIndexPath:indexPath];

}
```

However it seems like if I have 2 UItableViewCells in the same XIB, it will give me an error:
`invalid nib registered for identifier (historyCellType) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance'`

Is there anyway to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: i prefer to do custom UITableViewCell and handle ipad and iphone information . AT cellForRowAtIndexPath at uitableView handle cell width and height ..

Comment: @GeorgeHanna yea, but the problem is that I need to shift all the objects that were originally on the 2nd row into the 1st row. It seems easier if I just create another cell and have it all setup using AutoLayout

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to use differetnt cell for iPad and iPhone it is using 2 nibs:
**HistoryCell~iphone.xib** and **HistoryCell~ipad.xib**

And you must register you nib:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HistoryCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"historyCellType"];
```

System automatically loads xib depending on current device.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know about this neat trick. Is there anyway I can force it to default to the iPad version in the iPad Simulator? It seems to keep defaulting to the iPhone version. Thank you, Alexander!

Comment: Yoy are welcome! In iPad simulotor will be loaded HistoryCell~ipad.xib by default, if you want load specific nib you should be specify file name.